# Why does the compiler complains when I declare and define a constructor with no argument and a constructor with an argument?

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

I have this code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
    public:
        Object();
        Object(int someValue = 0);

    private:
        int value;
};

Object::Object()
{
    std::cout << "No argument constructor" << std::endl;
    value = 0;
}

Object::Object(int someValue)
{
    std::cout << "Argument constructor" << std::endl;
    value = someValue
}

int main()
{
    Object obj1;     // should call Object() (according to me)
    Object obj2(5);  // should call Object(int) (according to me)
}
```

But the compiler (MinGW 4.8.1) on Windows 7 64 bit, complains about a call of overloaded 'Object()' being ambiguous:

```
defaultConstructorTest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
defaultConstructorTest.cpp:27:9: error: call of overloaded 'Object()' is  ambiguous
  Object obj1;
         ^
defaultConstructorTest.cpp:27:9: note: candidates are:
defaultConstructorTest.cpp:19:1: note: Object::Object(int)
Object::Object(int someValue)
^
defaultConstructorTest.cpp:13:1: note: Object::Object()
Object::Object()
^
```

So ideally, I would like to get this output:

```
No argument constructor
Argument constructor
```

Comment: Because the compiler can't decide which constructor to use, the one with no arguments or the one with a single _defaulted_ argument. Not sure what the confusion is.

Comment: I guess less defaulted arguments *could* have been given a priority, but they weren't. We'd need a bunch of new rules to add to the already complex overload resolution section and it's debatable whether that priority is even logical. Here, there would be no way to call the constructor with a defaulted argument, so it's pretty pointless having one.

Comment: Remove the default value (keep the argument) of the parameterized constructor and your desired output will take flight.

Comment: When do you expect the `= 0` value to be used ?

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right!, I forgot how the default arguments work (sorry for my dumbness) I should have omitted the = 0 in the argument of the second constructor. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because call to

```
Object obj1;
```

is ambiguous. As second constructor has one default argument which makes it a good enough contender for default construction of objects.

Comment: Thanks!, I realize now my mistake, with the default argument of the second constructor I made ambiguous the call to the no argument constructor. If I remove the = 0 in the parameter I get the expected output.